# Picture library error: This library either no longer exists or has no images in it. Please select a different library

Tags: picture-library, slidelibrary

I am using sp 2010. I have created a new picture library. Add some pictures inside of it. After this I add a picture slideshow webpart on my home page. I selected my picture library and the default view. I got this error:

This library either no longer exists or has no images in it. Please select a different library.

Why do I got this error? I try also other views, but got the same error. I created a new view and selected it in my slideshow webpart, and got the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a similar issue, I have a picture library with more than 5,000 items - so my problem is threshold.

I created a filtered view by indexed field "Modified" (Last 30 days) - this case works for me (Picture Library Slideshow Web Part fetchs pictures), but view that has only restriction "Limit the total number of items returned to the specified amount" does not work in Slideshow Web Part.

View that filtered by indexed field "Modified by" (filter [Me]) works in Slideshow Web Part - I had to create two view "Created by Me" and "Modified by Me", reason operation OR takes all items in the list.
All views show pictures normaly when I navigate to them directly.

I see the problem in my log  - threshold, but in your case problem may be different, but it should apear in the log. Please check your log.