# Picture library slideshow webpart SharePoint 2019 On-Premise

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem

I am using SharePoint 2019 On-Premise. I have created a new picture library. Add some pictures inside of it. After this, I add a picture slideshow webpart on my home page. I selected my picture library and the default view. I got this error:

**This library either no longer exists or has no images in it. Please select a different library.**

"Why do I got this error? I try also other views, but got the same error. I created a new view and selected it in my slideshow webpart, and got the same error.
In my virtual (VMWare server) workspace works great, but in test server environment i got described error."

I found similar post here:
[Picture library error: This library either no longer exists or has no images in it. Please select a different library](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/122550/picture-library-error-this-library-either-no-longer-exists-or-has-no-images-in)
I cannot found any related information in event log.

FYI: I tried upgrade sharepoint to the newest version and not helped me...
I go step by step from this tutorial: https://sharepointmaven.com/add-slideshow-sharepoint-site/ and more others tutorials...
I just found only a small discrepancy in field preview picture(Field Internal Name= "PreviewOnForm"). This field not showing in server environment, it can be error, but I don't know how to repair it...

**More Info:**

We use sharepoint 2019 on premise 16.0.10371.20043 February 2021 Patch.

I made up first -> Team template(modern design) -> then picture library (classical mode)->

**and there is result**:

**On Server:**
[[image: Result on server1]

**On Local:**
[image: Result on Local]

Comparison of server and local version:

**Server:**
[image: Server version]

**Local:**
[image]

**In my humble opinion:**

Last but not least, we tried so many times iisreset, sp-farm upgrade, psconfig, configuration wizard...

The last thing that occurs to me is that there were ongoing updates on the local server, while they were on the server and turned on only now (after 1 year).

**Error from ULSLog:**

```
03/02/2021 12:10:16.87  Project.suffix.TJ.Eld (0x20F0)  0x0154  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ag6b2   High        Duplicate content type definition detected for content type 0x01004613D6562E4C41A7B9DADDAC1689E00D, skipping.    
03/02/2021 12:10:16.87  Project.suffix.TJ.Eld (0x20F0)  0x0154  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ag6b2   High        Duplicate content type definition detected for content type 0x0101002039C03B61C64EC4A04F5361F3851066, skipping.  
03/02/2021 12:10:16.87  Project.suffix.TJ.Eld (0x20F0)  0x0154  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ag6b2   High        Duplicate content type definition detected for content type 0x0101002039C03B61C64EC4A04F5361F3851066, skipping.  
03/02/2021 12:10:16.87  Project.suffix.TJ.Eld (0x20F0)  0x0154  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ag6b2   High        Duplicate content type definition detected for content type 0x0101002039C03B61C64EC4A04F5361F385106605, skipping.    
03/02/2021 12:10:16.87  Project.suffix.TJ.Eld (0x20F0)  0x0154  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ag6b2   High        Duplicate content type definition detected for content type 0x0101002039C03B61C64EC4A04F5361F385106605, skipping.    
03/02/2021 12:10:16.87  Project.suffix.TJ.Eld (0x20F0)  0x0154  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ag6b2   High        Duplicate content type definition detected for content type 0x010100C5033D6CFB8447359FB795C8A73A2B19, skipping.  
03/02/2021 12:10:16.87  Project.suffix.TJ.Eld (0x20F0)  0x0154  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ag6b2   High        Duplicate content type definition detected for content type 0x010100C5033D6CFB8447359FB795C8A73A2B19, skipping.  



03/02/2021 12:10:17.28  Project.suffix.TJ.Eld (0x20F0)  0x0154  SharePoint Foundation           General                         b9y3    High        Failed to open the file 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\Template\Features\Project.suffix.Dokumenty_Dokumenty_WebContent\Resources\Resources.cs-CZ.resx'.    
03/02/2021 12:10:17.28  Project.suffix.TJ.Eld (0x20F0)  0x0154  SharePoint Foundation           General                         b9y4    High        #2006e: Zadaná cesta  neexistuje.    
03/02/2021 12:10:17.28  Project.suffix.TJ.Eld (0x20F0)  0x0154  SharePoint Foundation           General                         b9y9    High        Failed to read resource file "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\Template\Features\Project.suffix.Dokumenty_Dokumenty_WebContent\Resources\Resources.cs-CZ.resx" from feature id "858a5f6a-2b36-4ce4-a079-de0e39b40525".    
03/02/2021 12:10:17.28  Project.suffix.TJ.Eld (0x20F0)  0x0154  SharePoint Foundation           General                         8e26    Medium      Failed to open the language resource for Fea858a5f6a-2b36-4ce4-a079-de0e39b40525 keyfile Resources.  
03/02/2021 12:10:17.28  Project.suffix.TJ.Eld (0x20F0)  0x0154  SharePoint Foundation           General                         b9y3    High        Failed to open the file 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\Template\Features\Project.suffix.Dokumenty_Dokumenty_WebContent\Resources\Resources.resx'.  
03/02/2021 12:10:17.28  Project.suffix.TJ.Eld (0x20F0)  0x0154  SharePoint Foundation           General                         b9y4    High        #2006e: Zadaná cesta  neexistuje.    
03/02/2021 12:10:17.28  Project.suffix.TJ.Eld (0x20F0)  0x0154  SharePoint Foundation           General                         b9y9    High        Failed to read resource file "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\Template\Features\Project.suffix.Dokumenty_Dokumenty_WebContent\Resources\Resources.resx" from feature id "858a5f6a-2b36-4ce4-a079-de0e39b40525".  


03/02/2021 11:35:54.62  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x101C)                       0x043C  SharePoint Foundation           Usage Infrastructure            ajykt   High        Deleting usage log file 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\LOGS\TaskUsage\SRVNT56-SHP2019-20210225-1031-20210225-10360.usage' after data import.  f04ab09f-4595-d017-d890-67bbcf6e4be5
03/02/2021 11:35:54.62  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x101C)                       0x043C  SharePoint Foundation           Usage Infrastructure            851y    High        No usage log files to import where found with filter 'ServerName-????????-????-????????-????*.usage'.   f04ab09f-4595-d017-d890-67bbcf6e4be5


03/02/2021 11:35:55.30  wsstracing.exe (0x0C94)                     0x152C  SharePoint Foundation           Unified Logging Service         adr4q   Unexpected  Trace Service encountered an unexpected exception when processing usage event. Detail exception message: Create store file error.. Win32 error code=5.   
03/02/2021 11:35:55.34  wsstracing.exe (0x0C94)                     0x152C  SharePoint Foundation           Unified Logging Service         adr4q   Unexpected  Trace Service encountered an unexpected exception when processing usage event. Detail exception message: Create store file error.. Win32 error code=5.
03/02/2021 11:35:55.36  wsstracing.exe (0x0C94)                     0x152C  SharePoint Foundation           Unified Logging Service         adr4q   Unexpected  Trace Service encountered an unexpected exception when processing usage event. Detail exception message: Create store file error.. Win32 error code=5.   
03/02/2021 11:35:55.42  wsstracing.exe (0x0C94)                     0x152C  SharePoint Foundation           Unified Logging Service         adr4q   Unexpected  Trace Service encountered an unexpected exception when processing usage event. Detail exception message: Create store file error.. Win32 error code=5.   
03/02/2021 11:35:55.46  wsstracing.exe (0x0C94)                     0x152C  SharePoint Foundation           Unified Logging Service         adr4q   Unexpected  Trace Service encountered an unexpected exception when processing usage event. Detail exception message: Create store file error.. Win32 error code=5.
03/02/2021 11:35:55.49  wsstracing.exe (0x0C94)                     0x152C  SharePoint Foundation           Unified Logging Service         adr4q   Unexpected  Trace Service encountered an unexpected exception when processing usage event. Detail exception message: Create store file error.. Win32 error code=5.   

03/02/2021 11:35:56.59  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x101C)                       0x10A0  SharePoint Server Search        Administration                  eff0    High        synchronizing search data access service instance   f14ab09f-1513-d017-d890-637c4fe3a985
03/02/2021 11:35:56.65  wsstracing.exe (0x0C94)                     0x152C  SharePoint Foundation           Unified Logging Service         adr4q   Unexpected  Trace Service encountered an unexpected exception when processing usage event. Detail exception message: Create store file error.. Win32 error code=5.   
03/02/2021 11:35:56.90  wsstracing.exe (0x0C94)                     0x152C  SharePoint Foundation           Unified Logging Service         adr4q   Unexpected  Trace Service encountered an unexpected exception when processing usage event. Detail exception message: Create store file error.. Win32 error code=5.   
03/02/2021 11:35:57.32  wsstracing.exe (0x0C94)                     0x152C  SharePoint Foundation           Unified Logging Service         adr4q   Unexpected  Trace Service encountered an unexpected exception when processing usage event. Detail exception message: Create store file error.. Win32 error code=5.
03/02/2021 11:35:57.69  wsstracing.exe (0x0C94)                     0x152C  SharePoint Foundation           Unified Logging Service         adr4q   Unexpected  Trace Service encountered an unexpected exception when processing usage event. Detail exception message: Create store file error.. Win32 error code=5.   

03/02/2021 11:35:58.22  w3wp.exe (0x23F4)                           0x0D54  SharePoint Server Search        Query                           agx9g   High        Search 'Web Parts and Support Files' feature 'eaf6a128-0482-4f71-9a2f-b1c650680e77' is no activated.    f14ab09f-4576-d017-d890-605673997d96

03/02/2021 11:35:58.22  w3wp.exe (0x23F4)                           0x0D54  SharePoint Portal Server        Search Boxes                    ahvv6   Unexpected  Fetching app info failed: Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchServiceNotFoundException   f14ab09f-4576-d017-d890-605673997d96
03/02/2021 11:35:58.25  wsstracing.exe (0x0C94)                     0x152C  SharePoint Foundation           Unified Logging Service         adr4q   Unexpected  Trace Service encountered an unexpected exception when processing usage event. Detail exception message: Create store file error.. Win32 error code=5.   

03/02/2021 11:35:58.31  w3wp.exe (0x23F4)                           0x0D54  SharePoint Portal Server        Search Boxes                    ahvv6   Unexpected  Fetching app info failed: Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchServiceNotFoundException   f14ab09f-4576-d017-d890-605673997d96

03/02/2021 11:35:58.32  w3wp.exe (0x23F4)                           0x0D54  SharePoint Foundation           General                         agxkz   High        calling GetCurrentGenericSetupPath for a versioned path: TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS   f14ab09f-4576-d017-d890-605673997d96
03/02/2021 11:35:58.32  w3wp.exe (0x23F4)                           0x0D54  SharePoint Foundation           General                         agxkz   High        calling GetCurrentGenericSetupPath for a versioned path: TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS   f14ab09f-4576-d017-d890-605673997d96
03/02/2021 11:35:58.32  w3wp.exe (0x23F4)                           0x0D54  SharePoint Foundation           General                         agxkz   High        calling GetCurrentGenericSetupPath for a versioned path: TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS   f14ab09f-4576-d017-d890-605673997d96
03/02/2021 11:35:58.32  w3wp.exe (0x23F4)                           0x0D54  SharePoint Foundation           General                         agxkz   High        calling GetCurrentGenericSetupPath for a versioned path: TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS   f14ab09f-4576-d017-d890-605673997d96
03/02/2021 11:35:58.33  w3wp.exe (0x23F4)                           0x0D54  SharePoint Foundation           General                         agxkz   High        calling GetCurrentGenericSetupPath for a versioned path: TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS   f14ab09f-4576-d017-d890-605673997d96
03/02/2021 11:35:58.33  w3wp.exe (0x23F4)                           0x0D54  SharePoint Foundation           General                         agxkz   High        calling GetCurrentGenericSetupPath for a versioned path: TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS   f14ab09f-4576-d017-d890-605673997d96
03/02/2021 11:35:58.33  w3wp.exe (0x23F4)                           0x0D54  SharePoint Foundation           General                         agxkz   High        calling GetCurrentGenericSetupPath for a versioned path: TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS   f14ab09f-4576-d017-d890-605673997d96


03/02/2021 11:35:58.34  w3wp.exe (0x23F4)                           0x0D54  SharePoint Server Search        Query                           dn4s    High        FetchDataFromURL start at(outside if): 1 param: start   f14ab09f-4576-d017-d890-605673997d96
03/02/2021 11:35:58.35  w3wp.exe (0x23F4)                           0x0D54  SharePoint Server Search        Query                           ajhum   High        Exception in LogTimingsToETW: Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchServiceNotFoundException   f14ab09f-4576-d017-d890-605673997d96

03/02/2021 11:35:58.52  wsstracing.exe (0x0C94)                     0x152C  SharePoint Foundation           Unified Logging Service         adr4q   Unexpected  Trace Service encountered an unexpected exception when processing usage event. Detail exception message: Create store file error.. Win32 error code=5.
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: I'm not able to replicate with the Feb 2021 PUs applied using a classic Team site following the guide you linked. Do you have any ULS logs or at the very least, Console log from your browser?

Comment: Have you tried to rebuild a pic library to test whether it works?